# time difference count in javascript

Tags: javascript

Does anyone how can I do a time difference count in Javascript?

Example:

If I have the following time (24H format)

```
startTime = 0615
endTime = 1530
breakTime = 0030
```

how can I get the following output?

```
diffB4Break = 7.15 hours
afterBreak = 6.45 hours
```

Comment: `0030` - is that a string or something? If not, it would get interpreted as an octal number literal and equal 24_10

Answer (score 1):

There are complications here, for example you would need to know what the maximum shift was, and whether it is possible for a worker to be scheduled to work over the threshold of a day, i.e. start work at 2300 and finish at 0900.

It very quickly becomes clear why it's better to use a Date/Time object to handle dates and time-deltas.

In Javascript have a look at [`Date`](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Guffa's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1944929/1057429):

```
function parseTime(s) {
   var c = s.split(':');
   return parseInt(c[0]) * 60 + parseInt(c[1]);
}
var startTime = '6:45';
var endTime = '15:30';
var diff = parseTime(endTime) - parseTime(startTime);           
var min = diff % 60;
var hrs = parseInt(diff / 60);
alert(hrs + ":" + min);
```